# Implement and merge two stack in O(1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, merge, linked-list, stack

I've been asked this question somewhere.

I've been given 2 stacks. I have to implement the following operations:

```java
// Pass one of the stacks and a value to insert
push(Stack stack, value)    
pop(Stack stack, val)    
merge(Stack s1, Stack s2)
```

I have to perform above stack operations like `push` and `pop` in *O(1)*. So far I've used a linked list to successfully implement these operations.

But how can I merge the two stacks in *O(1)*? I couldn't find how to do it in *O(1)*.

Maybe I need to use some other data structure or something?

Comment: Well, when you merge, you pop() all elements from one stack and push into another. Is the main catch about maintaining the order of the popping stack values?

Comment: What does *merge* mean in this context? Should the elements of one stack be placed on top of the other, or should the values alternate from one stack and the other, or still something else?

Comment: It is also strange to have the `pop` implemented with 2 arguments. One would expect the `pop` function to *return* the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really easy if your stack objects keep both ends of the stack (top/botton, start/end, head/tail, whatever). I'll use top/bottom for this answer.

When you implement push/pop you operate on the top object. The bottom will remain the same (unless the stack is empty) and the node that represents it will have it's next pointer set to null.

So to merge two stacks you take the bottom of one, point it to the top of the other and return a "new" stack formed of the other pointers.

```
Stack merge(Stack s1, Stack s2) {
  // join the stacks
  s2.bottom.next = s1.top

  // make a nice object to give back
  Stack result;
  result.bottom = s1.bottom
  result.top = s2.top

  // cleanup the parameters so they don't mess up the new structure.
  s1.bottom = s1.top = s2.bottom = s2.top = null;

  return result;
}
```

If you don't have the two pointers nicely kept in the stack object you would need to traverse one of the stacks get what would be kept here as bottom, making the complexity O(N).

Comment: yeah .. This will work . if i maintain a pointer at last during push operations.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give another perspective, the programming/object oriented perspective. If you do not have a pointed to the end of the stack as suggested before and **in case merging means first return the elements of one stack, then the other, i.e. define an order between them** - this is a real important consideration you did not address. You could follow the following approach

Create a `StackList` object which extends `Stack` Java example:

```
class StackList extends Stack
```

Now, hold a linked list of Stacks in it, the merging is trivial by adding the Stacks to the list, `pop/push` will simply call the `pop/push` methods of the head Stack.